# Разбор HTML-кода

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, парсер

Имеется код выпадающего меню:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я извлекаю даты начала киносеансов из тега option.
В некоторых select может быть больше одного option. 
Как мне различить option из одного select?
По атрибуту 'data-id' пробовал - пишет, что undefined.
Заранее спасибо.
Вот так извлекаю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если просто положить в массив даты, то

```
 let dateArr = [];

$('select').each( (ind) => {
    const data = $(this).find('option').text();
    dateArr.push(data);
})
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Именно то, что я хотел.

Comment: отметь ответ правильным, вдруг кому-то понадоится